# Jersey @FormDataParam to read multiple InputStream files

Tags: java, jersey, multipartform-data

I could able to use below code to upload a single photo, but I want to upload multiple photos with `@FormDataParam`

```
@POST
@Path("data/uploadPhoto")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadPhoto(@FormDataParam("data") InputStream photo) {
```

I tried to use `@FormDataParam("file") List<InputStream> photos`

but its not worked out, any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting multiple files and uploading them using Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749472/selecting-multiple-files-and-uploading-them-using-jersey)

Answer (score 0):

Since each part of the request must have a unique name, you can not use the same name `file` for every image. The request must use *different* names.

It followes that your method must have one `@FormDataParam` for each file in the request. All of these must have different names.

```
public Response uploadPhoto(@FormDataParam("data1") InputStream photo1,
  @FormDataParam("data2") InputStream photo2,
  @FormDataParam("data3") InputStream photo3) {
```

Comment: thanks for the response, here photos are dynamic and I don't know how many of the photos will come in the request, so wanted to handle in a generic way.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload multiple Files by Using FormDataBodyPart Class which allows you to get the form data and you can grab the multiple images as InputStream from it.

I've posted a sample below,

```
 @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public void uploadMultiple(@FormDataParam("file") FormDataBodyPart body){
        for(BodyPart part : body.getParent().getBodyParts()){
            InputStream is = part.getEntityAs(InputStream.class);
            ContentDisposition meta = part.getContentDisposition();
            doUpload(is, meta);
        }
    }
```

> You Question possible duplicate of [Selecting multiple files and uploading them using Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749472/selecting-multiple-files-and-uploading-them-using-jersey)